# How to derive the metric for a 2-sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

I have a question in Polchinski's string theory vol I p 167. It is said

> For example,
>   $$ds^2= \frac{ 4 r^2 dz d \bar{z} }{(1+ z \bar{z})^2} = \frac{ 4 r^2 du d\bar{u}}{ (1+ z \bar{z})^2} \tag{6.1.3}$$
>   describes a sphere of radius $r$ and curvature $R=2/r^2$.

Why Eq. (6.1.3) describes a sphere of radius $r$ and curvature $R=2/r^2$? How to derive it?

[I tried to use $z=\sigma_1 + i \sigma_2$ and $\bar{z} = \sigma_1 - i \sigma_2$ coordinates. By $dz d\bar{z} = 2 d \sigma_1 d \sigma_2$, I got
$$ ds^2= \frac{ 8 r^2 d \sigma_1 d \sigma_2 }{ (1+ \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2)^2} $$

By any means I have imagined, it does not look like a sphere.]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried to search round metric before I post this question, but did not find a satisfactory (for me) explanation. E.g. [Only gives result](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere)

Comment: $d{\bar z} dz \neq 2 d\sigma_{1}d\sigma_{2}$

Comment: I tried. But $ds^2 = d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta\,d\phi^2$ does not bring to (6.1.3)....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Writing :

$x_1 = \sin \theta \cos \phi$,
$x_2 = \sin \theta \sin \phi$,
$x_3 = \cos \theta $

The unit radius $2$-sphere metrics is $ds^2=(d\theta^2 + \sin^2 \theta ~d\phi^2)$

We are going to use the stereographic projection : $ \large z = \frac {x_1+ix_2}{1-x_3}$

This gives : $z = cotg(\theta/2) ~e^{i \phi}$

So, $$  dz = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{-1}{\sin^2 (\theta/2)})~e^{i \phi} ~d\theta + i~cotg(\theta/2) ~e^{i \phi}~ d\phi$$

$$  d \bar z = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{-1}{\sin^2 (\theta/2)})~e^{-i \phi} ~d\theta - i~cotg(\theta/2) ~e^{-i \phi}~ d\phi$$

We have :

$$1 + z \bar z = 1 + cotg^2(\theta/2) = \frac{1}{sin^2(\theta/2)}$$

$$dz d \bar z = \frac{1}{4} \frac{1}{sin^4(\theta/2)} ~d\theta^2 + cotg^2(\theta/2)~~d\phi^2$$

Finally,

$$\frac{4  ~dz ~d \bar z}{(1 + z \bar z)^2} = d \theta^2 + sin^2\theta ~~d\phi^2$$

We then multiply by $r^2$ to get the metrics of a sphere of radius $r$

Comment: Thank you very much! Concerning multiplying by $r^2$, if I start from the stereographic projection with a sphere with radius $r$, will I get $z= r \frac{ x_1 + i x_2}{ r- x_3} = r \cot (\theta/2) e^{i \phi} $? It differs a factor of $r$. But in the last expression $\frac{ 4 dz d \bar{z}}{ (1+ z \bar{z})^2}$, the numerator enlarges as $r^2$, the denominator changes as $(1+r^2 z_0 \bar{z}_0)^2$, where $z_0$ and $\bar{z}_0$ denotes to the value for radius 1. I didn't get the multiply by $r^2$ result

Comment: No, if you begin with a sphere of radius $r$, you have to write the stereographic projection as : $\large z = \frac {x_1/r+ix_2/r}{1-x_3/r} = \frac{x_1+ix_2}{r-x_3}$

Comment: So, all the calculus is the same, because the expression of $z$ is the same. $z$ has no dimension.

Comment: Then by $x_1=r\sin \theta \cos \phi$ similar for $x_2$ and $x_3$, I have $z=\cot (\theta/2) e^{i \phi}$,  $\frac{ 4 dz d \bar{z}}{ 1+ z \bar{z}}^2 = d \theta^2 + \sin^2 \theta^2 d \phi^2 $, still remains the same. Where to get $r^2$?

Comment: Yes, the last equation is always true, but because the metrics of the sphere of radius $r$ is $ds^2=r^2(d\theta^2 + \sin^2 \theta ~d\phi^2)$, you have to multiply the last expression by $r^2$

Comment: I see!! Factor $r^2$ appears in (6.1.3).

Comment: By the way, I have another question to make sure. Are the transformation of metric and volume element different? The first one is $dz d\bar{z}= (\partial z /\partial \theta + \partial z /\partial \phi ) (\partial \bar{z} /\partial \theta + \partial \bar{z} /\partial \phi ) d \theta d\phi$; the volume element is in-principle a wedge product $dz \wedge d\bar{z} = J(z,\bar{z};\theta,\phi) d \theta \wedge d \phi$. $J$ denotes to the Jacob's determinant ?

Comment: Wedge product is correct, change of variables is $dz  d\bar{z} = |J(z,\bar{z};\theta,\phi)| d \theta d \phi$